# Got unexpected output in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, subclass

I have some java Code:

```
class Protected{
    int n = 1;

    public Protected(){
        System.out.println("Constructor of protected");
        System.out.println("========================");
        System.out.println("n = "+n);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
class Derived extends Protected{
    Derived(){
        System.out.println("Constructor of derived");
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println("n = "+(n+1));
    }
}

public class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Derived ob2 = new Derived();
    }
}
```

I got the output as:

```
constructor of protected
========================
n=1

constructor of Derived
========================
n=2
```

This is what I want:

```
constructor of Derived
========================
n=2
```

Comment: You cannot prevent a super class initialising.  You shouldn't put side effects into the constructor, instead you should add a method for printing this information and have it overridden. Then it will do what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A superclass constructor must be called for every new instance of a subclass.  If you don't supply an explicit call to a superclass constructor in your subclass constructor, then Java will insert an implicit call to the no-argument superclass constructor.  This explains why you see the output of your superclass constructor.

To remove that output, you can do one of the following:

1) Remove the output statements from the superclass constructor.

2) Create another constructor in the superclass that doesn't output anything, and explicitly call it in the subclass constructor.

[Section 8.8.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) states:

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is happening *implicitly*:

```
class Derived extends Protected{
        Derived(){
        super(); // <--- This is called whether you want to or not
        System.out.println("Constructor of derived");
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println("n = "+(n+1));
    }
```

There is absolutely no way to do this in Java; it would break the language specification. Don't put a print statement in the base class if the printing is not desired.

[JLS 12 Execution / 12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.5)

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor [...]
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using `this`), then [...]
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using `this`). *If this constructor is for a class other than* `Object`, *then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor* (using `super`).
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class [...]
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor [...]

Answer (score 0):

You should not extend the super class to get the desired output. Or You can define another overloaded Constructor in Super class and, you need to call it explicitly in sub class Constructor.

When a sub class Constructor invoked, before the constructor's body get executed, Super class Constructor will be called, Hence the output of you program.